# Limit scope of included platform header to to just the header file including it?

Tags: c++, header, include

I'm working on a C++ library project. I need to include a platform specific header to get access to some `#defines`.  The catch is, I only want the platform's header visible within my my header. For those including my header, I don't want them to see the additional symbols.

I thought about using a C++ namespace to contain/control the symbol visibility, but it does not work (confer, [#define statements within a namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1088290)). And as far as I know, options like [`--exclude-libs,all`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) only applies to library symbols at link time, and not header symbols.

I also thought about using the symbols I need from the platform header, and then undefining all the symbols it includes. But I don't know how to wildcard `#undef platform_header.h/*`.

There's a similar question at [Including a header file into a header file without exposing it's content to the includer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25062122). He's doing it to limit IDE auto-completion, which is producing different answers than I need because of different requirements.

How can I limit the visibility of an included platform header to just my library header?

Comment: A mechanism to support this, `#scope`, was proposed http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1614.pdf but never got adopted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, in general, avoid macro name pollution. The only tool at your disposal is the **compiler firewall**, to include the C (or just troublesome) header in an implementation file. You then provide your own C++ interface to that, in your header file.

Comment: Thanks Cheers. So I'm clear: there's no way to wildcard the `undef`? (I think that was the open question I had).

Comment: Not with standard functionality, and I'm not aware of any language extensions to do it.